# Calculate the maximum euclidean distance from a MST (minimal spanning tree)

Tags: matlab, max, euclidean-distance

**Task**: I am working in Matlab and I have to construct a dendrogram from maximum values of a matrix of Euclidean distance.

**What have I done so far**: I have constructed the distance matrix based on the correlation coefficients of returns of prices (this is what I have in my application). I have also built the MST based on these distances. Now I have to construct the ultrametric matrix which is obtained by defining the subdominant ultrametric distance D*ij between i and j as the maximum value of any Euclidean distance Dkl detected by moving in single steps from i to j in the MST.

```
CorrelMatrix=corrcoef(Returns); 
DistMatrix=sqrt(2.*(1-CorrelMatrix)); 
DG=sparse(DistMatrix);
[ST,pred] = graphminspantree(DG,'Method','Prim');
Z = linkage(DistMatrix);
dendrogram(Z)
```

I am a newbie in Matlab and I do not know if there is a function or something that I should use to find the maximum distance between two nodes, and to put if after in a matrix.

Comment: Please show us the actual code you have tried. The reason why showing us what code you wrote is because quite often, the solution to your answer can be found by making slight adjustments to your code. You get an answer faster, and it's less time spent on our part to help you - a win-win situation. This also prevents us from having to redo any setup or data calculations you made. Showing us what code you've written so far will go a very long way in terms of getting someone to help you. If you're not convinced, see the How To Ask link on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In light of this, have you considered finding the convex hull of your graph instead?  The property of convex hull is that it inherently finds the maximum distance for you between any two nodes in your graph.

Comment: @rayryeng I looked over convex hull and I don't think it can solve my problem...